# What does Sequelize's findOne method return?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to create a controller that creates a new pokemon but first I want to know if it exists in my database (postgres) and if it exists, return the corresponding error.

When I make a post with insomnia, if the pokemon doesn't exist, it creates it and gives me the corresponding message. If the pokemon exists it gives me the message that `was created correctly` but it doesn't add it to the database and my app breaks.

I need that if the pokemon exists in my database, the error message is seen on the client and that my server does not break.

My controller:

```js
const { Pokemon } = require('../db')

const postPokemon = async (name, health, attak, def, speed, height, weight) => {
    const search = await Pokemon.findOne({ where: { name }})
    if(search !== null){
        return `Ya existe un pokemon con el nombre ${name}`
    } else{
        const createPokemon = await Pokemon.create({name, health, attak, def, speed, height,        weight})

        return createPokemon
    } 
}

module.exports = {
    postPokemon
}
```

Post router:

```js
pokemonsRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        const { name, health, attak, def, speed, height, weight } = req.body
        if(!name) throw new Error(`El campo nombre no puede estar vacio`)
        postPokemon(name, health, attak, def, speed, height, weight)
        res.status(200).send(`El pokemon ${name} fue creado correctamente`)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
})
```

Error console:

```
pokemon-main\api\src\controllers\postPokemons.js:6
        throw new Error(`Ya existe un pokemon con el nombre ${name}`)
              ^

     Error: Ya existe un pokemon con el nombre Charmander
      at postPokemon (C:\Users\crist\OneDrive\Escritorio\hc\PIs\PI-Pokemon-main\PI-Pokemon-       main\api\src\controllers\postPokemons.js:6:15)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I did it according to the sequelize documentation:

findOne

The findOne method obtains the first entry it finds (that fulfills the optional query options, if provided).

```js
const project = await Project.findOne({ where: { title: 'My Title' } });
if (project === null) {
   console.log('Not found!');
} else {
      console.log(project instanceof Project); // true
      console.log(project.title); // 'My Title'
}
```

Maybe I should do that validation on the routes or maybe I can't use it with throw new Error.

Comment: At least you forgot to use `await` while calling `postPokemon`

Comment: Yes you have the await the postpokemon promise fullfillment, and also when the pokemon exists you are just returning a string and not throwing an error so you will return a 200 anyway.